# Cómo guardar palabras de un fichero de texto en una matriz en C?

Tags: c

Tengo un fichero de texto con palabras y quiero guardar las palabras de una dimensión determinada en una una matriz
por ejemplo, tengo este fichero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esto:

```
int main()
```

{

```
int dim=6;
int letras=3;
char mat[6][10];
FILE *fichero;
int i=0;
fichero= fopen("prova.txt", "r");
while(!feof(fichero))
    fscanf(fichero, "%s", mat[i++]);
fclose(fichero);

for (i=0;i<dim;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<letras;j++){
        if (strlen(mat[i])==letras){

            printf("%s\n",mat[i]);

            break;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Como letras=3 me mostrará por pantalla:
ABC
ABB
ACC
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero guardar estos resultados en una matriz 3x3

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Al menos averiguaste cómo abrir y leer un archivo?

Comment: Sí, he conseguido abrir y leer el archivo, incluso he conseguido imprimir por pantalla las palabras de un tamaño en concreto. Lo que no consigo hacer es guardar dichas palabras en una matriz

Comment: Un par de dudas. ¿Por qué cierras el archivo en la primera iteración? ¿El uso del segundo for es para filtrar solo las palabras con 3 caracteres o menos? ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de como quisieras que se guarden los resultados en una matriz 3x3?